# Convert one hot encoding of 45 numbers and I have list of eachone six

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, scikit-learn

I have this kind of numbers list [ 7.,  8., 20., 29., 33., 38.] and In this kind of numbers are from 1 to 45 any 6 numbers how I can convert this into onehot encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

otp = []
for i in range(1,46):
try:
list(array).index(i)
otp.append(1)

except:
otp.append(0)

where array is my siz numbers and it will create a list of 45 numbers.